# How to convert a date in an order by statement? (MySQL)

Tags: mysql, sql, asp.net

I'm trying to order my results by date, but the dates are strings, not date objects, so the results aren't showing up properly. I tried converting the date string to a date object in the sql request, but now nothing returns. There are no results showing on the screen. Here's my code:

```
SELECT * FROM tblnewsftb 
WHERE Status = 'Active'
ORDER BY CONVERT(datetime, ItemDate, 102) DESC
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You have to show the format of your string and use: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date

Comment: Do times display in those dates? e.g. 2020-05-09 15:29:00? As mentioned, showing the specific format of your string would be helpful. You could try using TIMESTAMP instead of DATETIME if that helps - and perhaps use ALTER TABLE to convert the data type as opposed to the above.

Comment: Are you sure you are using MySQL?  That syntax is SQL Server syntax.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I am using MySQL. That was the problem. I was using SQL syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, `CONVERT()` only takes two arguments, the expression and a data type. The data type goes second.

Example:

```
CONVERT(ItemDate, DATETIME)
```

But this will work only if the expression (your ItemDate column in this example) is convertible as-is to a DATETIME. I would guess you're using some date format that MySQL doesn't support, like 'MM/DD/YYYY' or something else.

You'll have to use [STR_TO_DATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) if you have a custom format.

Example:

```
STR_TO_DATE(ItemDate, '%m/%d/%Y')
```

It would really be best if you store datetime values in a proper DATETIME column instead of a string column if you want them to sort correctly.

Comment: `convert()`  has the possibility for 3 arguments. The data type, the string to be converted, and the style code. Is `ItemDate` a data type?

Comment: @steveo314, This question is tagged [tag:mysql]. [Microsoft SQL Server's implementation of the CONVERT() function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/cast-and-convert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) has a three-argument usage, but [MySQL's CONVERT() function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert) does not.

Comment: @BillKarwin the question wasn't tagged MySQL when I said that. The OP has been re written.